# Installed 14.04 Ubuntu desktop ..want to upgrade kernel

Tags: kernel

Whenever I boot into this OS, Im encountering lot of bugs which are making the system unstable and stop functioning. I have frequently found this error

```
bug soft lockup - cpu#0 stuck for 22s [chrome:2566]
```

after this error pops .. system simply freezes.

Googled a lot to solve this problem, one of the fix being upgrading the kernel. To do this first I checked my current kernel version

```
$ uname -a
Linux vikram-Vostro1310 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So my current version is 3.13.0-24, how do i upgrade to latest 'stable' kernel, does upgrading to kernel 3.14.1 solve all these problems as stated in this [link](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/04/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-14-1-in-linux.html)?

Is there a better 'stable' kernel which avoids the above bugs or should i just go forward and upgrade to 3.14.1 kernel as instructed in this [link](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/04/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-14-1-in-linux.html)

Kindly help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your hardware configuration please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not expert, it is strongly recommended to use standard kernel from system repository.

Newest and/or custom-builded kernels may be unstable.

Comment: I agree, 3.13 is pretty recent too, I think (but haven't verified) that your bug may not be kernel-version related.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade kernel to 3.16 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

or to 3.19 by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```